# Can I use json tags as bson tags in mgo?

Tags: json, go, bson, mgo

I am using `thrift` in my project, thrift will generate code as follow:

```
type CvJdRelationInfo struct {
    JdId            string `thrift:"jdId,1" json:"jdId"`
    CvId            string `thrift:"cvId,2" json:"cvId"`
    Status          int16  `thrift:"status,3" json:"status"`
    AcceptTimestamp int64  `thrift:"acceptTimestamp,4" json:"acceptTimestamp"`
}
```

as you see thrift already generate `json tags`(but `no bson tags`), when I use `mgo` save record, `mgo` will auto convert:

```
JdId -> jdid
CvId -> cvid
Status -> status
AcceptTimeStamp -> accepttimestamp
```

what I needed is:

```
type CvJdRelationInfo struct {
    JdId            string `thrift:"jdId,1" json:"jdId" bson:"jdId"`
    CvId            string `thrift:"cvId,2" json:"cvId" bson:"cvId"`
    Status          int16  `thrift:"status,3" json:"status" bson:"status"`
    AcceptTimestamp int64  `thrift:"acceptTimestamp,4" json:"acceptTimestamp" bson:"acceptTimestamp"`
}
```

as your can see, `bson tags` is the same as `json tags`. Can I use `json tags` as `bson tags`?

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB actually stores the data as binary JSON (bson), which is distinct from JSON. It's slightly confusing because if you access the database using the mongo shell, you get back raw JSON, but it's actually a conversion, it's not the storage format. So in storing the data to the database, the "mgo" driver serializes as **bson**.

This serializing ignores the `json` export keys, and chooses the appropriate name by defaulting to the lowercase version of your struct field. (See the [bson.Marshal go doc](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Marshal).) If you specify a `bson` export key, it will then ignore the struct field name and go with whatever you have specified as the `bson` export key.

For example,

```go
type User struct {
    Name string
    UserAge int `bson:"age"`
    Phone string `json:"phoneNumber"`
}
```

will result in the following structure in MongoDB:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "age": 0,
    "phone": ""
}
```

So it seems like your struct fields should handle most things for you.

The one 'gotcha' that you might not see until it bites you is, if you don't specify the `bson` export keys, you don't have the ability to do `bson:",omitempty"` for leaving out blank fields, or `bson:",inline"` for marshaling embedded (or nested) structs.

For instance, this is how you would handle embedded structs:

```
type Employee struct {
    User `bson:",inline"`
    JobTitle string
    EmployeeId string
    Salary int
}
```

These sorts of things are specified in that link I provided on bson.Marshal. Hope that helps!

Comment: Calling BSON "binary JSON" is inaccurate. There's no such thing as binary JSON.

Comment: @Flimzy you may be interested in these links 
http://bsonspec.org/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON

Comment: @Limatuz: Note the "JSON-like" terminology in the first sentence. JSON, by [very definition](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159) is text-based, and thus not "binary." Even a 1-to-1 binary representation of JSON (which BSON definitely is not) would still not be "binary JSON". CBOR is probably the closest standard to a 1-to-1 JSON-to-binary representation, but it's still obviously not "binary JSON".

Answer (score 2):

you can change the default encoder/decoder in the following way:

```
mongo_addr := "mongodb://localhost:27017/"
structcodec, _ := bsoncodec.NewStructCodec(bsoncodec.JSONFallbackStructTagParser)
rb := bson.NewRegistryBuilder()
// register struct codec
rb.RegisterDefaultEncoder(reflect.Struct, structcodec)
rb.RegisterDefaultDecoder(reflect.Struct, structcodec)
clientOptions := options.Client().SetRegistry(rb.Build()).ApplyURI(mongo_addr)

mgclient, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Now during marshaling/unmarshalling `json` tag is used instead of `bson`.
This trick is a particularly useful when you use tags that both `bson` and `json` belong to.

By the way, those clientOptions can be set on collection and database levels too

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post this.  I was left frustrated by the really bare example on this in the official docs (https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#hdr-Native_Go_Types).  Once I came across your post, how to add the structcodec instruction to the Mongo client became clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following (From thrift test file git.apache.org/thrift.git/lib/go/test/GoTagTest.thrift)

```
struct tagged {
    1: string string_thing,
    2: i64 int_thing (go.tag = "json:\"int_thing,string\""),
    3: optional i64 optional_int_thing
}
```